# Find the next occurrence for given day of the month

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I have integer values (`@dayOfMonth`) that can range from 1 to 31, how would I determine the next date that falls on that day of the month either in the remainder of the current month or in the next month?

In cases where `@dayOfMonth` is greater than the number of valid days in the month, the result should be the last day of the month. For example, if `@dayOfMonth` is 31, and today is 4/15/17, I would expect the result to be 4/30/17.

These are the results I expect for the following values:

```
@testDate = 4/15/17 and @dayOfMonth = 31, result should be 4/30/17
@testDate = 4/15/17 and @dayOfMonth = 30, result should be 4/30/17
@testDate = 4/15/17 and @dayOfMonth = 25, result should be 4/25/17
@testDate = 4/15/17 and @dayOfMonth = 7, result should be 5/7/17
@testDate = 4/15/17 and @dayOfMonth = 15, result should be 5/15/17
@testDate = 1/31/17 and @dayOfMonth = 31, result should be 2/28/17
@testDate = 12/25/15 and @dayOfMonth = 5, result should be 1/5/18
```

Comment: can you show a few more example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this accounts for all of the month related conditions of concern. Seems wordy but it gives the expected results. Note: Both `EOMONTH` and `DATEFROMPARTS` require at least SQL 2012.

```
DECLARE @testdate date
SET @testdate = '4/15/17'

DECLARE @dayOfMonth int
SET @dayOfMonth = 31

SELECT CASE WHEN @dayOfMonth > DAY(@testdate) AND @dayOfMonth > DAY(EOMONTH(@testdate)) THEN EOMONTH(@testDate)
            WHEN @dayOfMonth > DAY(@testdate) AND @dayOfMonth <= DAY(EOMONTH(@testdate)) THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@testDate),MONTH(@testDate),@dayOfMonth)
            WHEN @dayOfMonth <= DAY(@testdate) AND @dayOfMonth > DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,1,EOMONTH(@testdate))) THEN DATEADD(MONTH,1,EOMONTH(@testdate))
            WHEN @dayOfMonth <= DAY(@testdate) AND @dayOfMonth <= DAY(DATEADD(MONTH,1,EOMONTH(@testdate))) THEN DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH,1,@testDate)),MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,1,@testDate)),@dayOfMonth)
    END AS NextDisbursementDate
```